# javascript : save function to object

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I saved a function in an Object.

```
var obj = {
  name: 'bob',
  getName: function() {
    return this.name;
  }
};
console.log(obj.getName());
```

It shows 'bob'.
But when I saved this obj to Session or MongoDB, 
the function was disappeared.

```
Session.set('tmp', obj);
var tmpObj = Session.get('tmp');
console.log(tmpObj.getName());
```

This shows undefined.

I've tested JSON.stringify / parse also, it doesn't work.

How can I keep the function in the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases it is not possible. Technically you can serialize a function using `obj.getName.toString()`, which should return

```
function() {
    return this.name;
}
```

You could then run it with something like `eval("(" + functionString + ")()")`. But this pretty much always a bad idea.

If you want to store it into MongoDB, you probably want to use [Mongoose ODM](http://mongoosejs.com/), and custom [setter](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/getters-setters.html). This allows you to define a function on a Schema that describes objects stored in MongoDB, which should fulfill your needs.

```
var objSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    get: function(name) {
      return name; //Of course, you could manipulate this more if you want.
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I think mongoose could be one of a solution for this. But some of my guys told me that mongoose has a downside of lots of way. But thanks to let me know.

Answer (score 0):

In most contexts you cannot save functions. Try putting all variables into primitive properties instead, and after reloading the "dumb" object, reinitialize with methods like this:

```
var ObjMaker = function(attrs){
  this.name = attrs.name;
}

ObjMaker.greet = function(){
  return 'Hello ' + this.name;
}

var reloadedObj = { name: 'bob' };

var obj = new Obj(reloadedObj);

console.log(obj.greet());
```